# Are there any tools to recover files from a previously formatted WinNT drive?

Tags: filesystems, windows, ext4

I scratched the previous Windows NT filesystem, now I'm running Ubuntu. I've created the whole disk as EXT4.

Are there **any** tools to locate and save some previous Windows files from the original filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) does wonders, but for a large partition, it is time consuming and a monumental task to pick through the output of the tool.  During an install of an unnamed OS, an auto-partition and format was done rather than allowing the user to manually partition the disks.  An ext4 /home partition was made into an LVM and formatted.  The format was apparantly a quick format.  I halted the system immediately.  I tried various tools to try to recover the original ext4 partition, but these attempts failed.

Eventually I booted the [SysRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage), and tried PhotoRec.  As it needed as much free space on the system as was used on the overwritten drive, I needed to find a lot of storage.  SysRescueCD has [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) on it, so I mounted a large NAS drive on another system, and then was able to run PhotoRec.

PhotoRec can get some file extensions (pictures, mp3's, and so on) correct, but the file names were completely lost otherwise.  Nevertheless, it was possible to recover certain key files.  I got back about as much data as the drive had on it.  In my case, it was not worth a lot of effort to recover everything as there was over 100 GB of data, but what kind of time it takes is dependent on how important something was that was lost.

I've done this multiple times.  Once I had a drive that failed and used what amounted to [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) to snag a copy of the drive, then proceeded to recover most of 40 GB of mp3s.

Don't believe anyone that does not qualify the statement when they say there is no way to get files back.  Many formats are "quick" and do not erase data.

Comment: "over 100 MB of data" are you off by a few orders of magnitude there?

Comment: Yes.  It should have been over 100 GB.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

If you've overwritten the disk with a new partition as you've described then no, there are no tools that can resurrect your old filesystems.

There are a [number of other Q&A's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=recover%20partition) related to various topics on this SE site regarding the recovery of files from repartitioning of ones HDD, but I wouldn't not set your expectations too high.

You're likely not going to be able to get any of these files back, and will end up wasting countless hours, trying to push a boulder up a hill, only to have it roll back on you.

Comment: Hi,so far as i know, only some of diskspace are overwritten,when destroying prev partitions and createing new unix fs. Most of the disk space should be untouched. BR, alf

Comment: @alfred - you're likely never going to get these files back, it's just not possible. Sorry!